# How to find an event in sentry by job arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, sentry

I have a rails app, sidekiq and sentry.

I want to find event in sentry by job arguments.
Sample:
I have SomeJob which executed with arguments [{some_arg: 'Arg1'}]

Job failed with error and send event to sentry.

How I can find event by job arguments?

I try full-text search, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search in sentry is limited by what they allow you to search by.

From reading their [Search docs](https://docs.sentry.io/product/sentry-basics/search/searchable-properties/) briefly you can either use:

- sentry tags
- messages

Either way, you would want to [enrich your sentry events](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/ruby/enriching-events/context/).

For example, let's assume you will rescue from the error raised in your job

```rb
class SomeJob

  include Sidekiq::Worker
  
  def perform(args)

     # do stuff with args

  rescue StandardError
    SentryError.new(args: args)
  end
end
```

`SentryJobError` is really just a PORO that would be called by your job classes.

```rb
class SentryJobError

  def initialize(args:)
    return if Rails.env.development?
    
    Sentry.configure_scope do |scope|
      scope.set_context('job_args', { args: args })
      scope.set_context('message', 'job ${args[:some_arg]} failed')
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: thank you for answer